# sql query to add rows based on a time difference

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

i have a table that has the following columns : s.no,house_no,energy,time 
i want to find the total energy for each house for every one hour.
table :

```
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------+
| sno | house_no | time                | energy |
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------+
|   1 |        1 | 2014-10-20 10:00:00 |      5 |
|   2 |        1 | 2014-10-20 10:30:00 |     10 |
|   3 |        2 | 2014-10-20 10:00:00 |      7 |   
|   4 |        1 | 2014-10-20 11:01:00 |      3 |
|   5 |        2 | 2014-10-20 11:00:00 |     20 |
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

i am trying for 10-11 am.But this query sums the energy of the rows whose time value is greater than 11 am also.

```
SELECT house_no, sum( energy ) AS sum, time
FROM main
GROUP BY house_no
HAVING (
TIMESTAMPDIFF(
MINUTE , time, '2014-10-20 11:00:00' ) >0)
```

the result is :

```
+----------+------+---------------------+
| house_no | sum  | time                |
+----------+------+---------------------+
|        1 |   18 | 2014-10-20 10:00:00 |
|        2 |   27 | 2014-10-20 10:00:00 |
+----------+------+---------------------+
```

but the actual answer should be:

```
+----------+------+---------------------+
| house_no | sum  | time                |
+----------+------+---------------------+
|        1 |   15 | 2014-10-20 10:00:00 |
|        2 |   7 | 2014-10-20 10:00:00 |
+----------+------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the time also based on the hours

```
SELECT house_no, sum( energy ) AS sum, time
FROM main
GROUP BY house_no,DATE_FORMAT(time,'%d %b %Y %H')
HAVING (
TIMESTAMPDIFF(
MINUTE , time, '2014-10-20 11:00:00' ) >0)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ddc5b/3)

Comment: yeah it works.Using the where clause instead of the having clause itself solves the problem.